# Single Svg not displaying when changing display:none to display:block

Tags: javascript, css, svg

So I have an SVG Animation that I've been working on for quite some time now. I have recently introduced a feature that after the first scene enters the frame, the user is able to click the svg image and it will change to another of two scenes.

the problem I'm having is specifically to do with one scene that will not display. it is the second, or "night" scene, that will not display when animated to, but will be visible when it is the first scene to enter.

In the developer console I am able to see that this scene is being rendered into the layout—as a box model is being drawn, but the svg element is seemingly invisible. I have configured all three scenes to behave the same way so I'm not sure what is causing this one scene to misbehave.

I'm not to familiar with svg-specific properties, so if anyone could shed some light on what is going on in the code example, it would be much appreciated.

here is the link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Leviathan_The_Great/pen/KqbpdY). The code exceeded the amount SO would allow.

here is a quick reference of the javascript that is controlling scene transitions:

```
//sets up animation scene
(function setup() {
    activeScene.style.display = "unset";
    //this is likly why tweenmax is taking a 360 rotation in the next code section - the rotation transformation is absolute, not relative
    TweenMax.set(document.getElementsByClassName("Scene-Svg"), {
        rotation: 180
    });
    console.log("scene is setup");
})();

(function comeIn() {
    //apparently tweenmax is not defined here
    TweenMax.to(activeScene, 3, {
        delay: 0.9,
        rotation: "360_CW",
        ease: Bounce.easeOut
    });
    console.log("animation entered");
})();

function nextScene() {
    /*
        what this function needs to do:
        -get active scene
        -get next scene
        -make next scene visible
        -rotate active and next scene
        -make active scene invisable
        -somehow change the global variable of activeScene to the next scene
    */
    let randIndex,
        nextScene;  
    let notActiveSceneIndex = false;
    while(notActiveSceneIndex === false){
        randIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * scenes.length );
        if(  activeScene.id === undefined || scenes[randIndex].id === undefined ){
            throw new Error("an svg's id is set to undefined")   
        }
        else if(  activeScene.id === scenes[randIndex].id  ){
            continue                                 
        }else{
            console.log("randIndex :" + randIndex)
            nextScene = scenes[randIndex]
            notActiveSceneIndex = true;            
        }
    }
      
    nextScene.style.display = "block";
    TweenMax.to(nextScene, 1.5, { rotation: "360_CW",ease: Power1.easeOut });
    TweenMax.to(activeScene, 1.5, { rotation: "180_CCW", ease: Power1.easeOut, onComplete:onCompletion});
    
    var onCompletion = () => {
        activeScene.style.display = "none"
    }
    
    activeScene = nextScene   
    
    
    console.log("animation has left");
}
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, especially the `<clipPath>` elements all have `id="a"`. Remember, all `<svg>` subtrees are part of the same DOM.

Comment: @ccprog god bless your soul. That was exactly it.